# Qt - retrieving text from QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt

This seems like it should be very straightforward, and I hope I'm just accidentally overlooking something simple. I have a dialog in my Qt (4.7) project with a QTextBrowser object. At a certain point in the code, I need to access the text inside this QTextBrowser, but while I found functions in the docs to *set* the text, I'm not seeing anything to *get* the text. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `QTextEdit::toPlainText()` or `QTextEdit::toHtml()`, depending of what you set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In documentation you can see

> Inherits: QTextEdit.
>
> List of all members, including inherited members

So this should work for QTextBrowser `QString QTextEdit::toPlainText()`

i.e

```
QString text = textBrowser.toPlainText();
```